# Can an iPhone or iPad support native video playback inside of a window rather than fullscreen?

Tags: iphone

I need a video to be able to be played with a description at the bottom while in landscape, then when the phone switches orientation, it will go full screen. This is basically how the Youtube app works for most of the Androids, (take the Samsung Galaxy S4 for example). But I only want it to play videos that are already on the app, nothing online, no web. In fact, my app records and saves it's own videos.

If it can be supported, then could I use an object such as a view of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find the code I use to display my videos helpful. I call this from my main view controller. In the displayWithVideo section I set the video size for different orientations and devices.

There is a text method for displaying text below the video and some cleanup methods to remove the objects from the screen when you rotate or swipe to the next screen. I haven’t looked at it in a while, but it should be iOS7 ready.

```
   //
    //  ShowVideo.m
    //  Words for SLPs
    //
    //  Created by John Scarry on 7/26/13.
    //  Copyright 2013 Learning Fundamentals, Inc. All rights reserved.
    //

    @import MediaPlayer;
    #import "ShowVideo.h"

    @implementation ShowVideo

    // Needs to know about the parentView so it can decide where to put the picts/buttons
    - (id)initWithParentView:(UIView *)parentview  {

        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            _parentView = parentview;
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)displaywithVideo:(NSString *)videoName
                    withText:(NSString *)videoText
          withSwipeDirection:(NSString *)swipeDirection {

        [self removeAllObjectsFromParentView];

        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

        CGPoint midPoint;
        midPoint.x = self.parentView.bounds.origin.x + self.parentView.bounds.size.width/2;
        midPoint.y = self.parentView.bounds.origin.y + self.parentView.bounds.size.height/2;
        // Put the word and category on the screen    
        NSInteger xDirection = 1; // Put the new picture off the screen then transition in. 1 is rightToLeft, -1 is leftToRight
        if ([swipeDirection isEqualToString:@"leftToRight"]) xDirection = -1;

        //Pictures are rectangular - 400 x 300. Display 90% the width of the screen
        CGFloat pictRatio = .75; 

        CGSize windowSize =  self.parentView.bounds.size;
        CGFloat verticalOffset = 20;
        #pragma unused(verticalOffset)
        if ([[Utilities deviceType] isEqualToString:@"iPhone Retina4"]) verticalOffset = 100;

        CGFloat insetValue = 2;
        CGFloat pictWidth = 320;
        CGFloat pictHeight = pictWidth * pictRatio + (insetValue * 2); // 960/1280 or 498/664 on Picts for SLPs
        pictWidth = pictWidth + (insetValue * 2);
        UIEdgeInsets insets;
        insets.top = insets.bottom = insets.left = insets.right = insetValue;

        NSString *backGroundFrameName = @"ArticTypeFrame";
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            verticalOffset = 110;
            pictWidth = windowSize.width * .9f;
            pictHeight = pictWidth *pictRatio; // 960/1280 is best size
            insets.top = insets.bottom = insets.left = insets.right = 6;

            if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
                pictWidth = windowSize.width * .55f;
                pictHeight = pictWidth *pictRatio; // 960/1280
                verticalOffset = 30;
            }

        // iPhone
        } else {
            if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
                pictWidth = windowSize.width * .3f;
                pictHeight = pictWidth *pictRatio; // 960/1280
                verticalOffset = 10;
            } else {
                verticalOffset = 60;
            }

        }

        CGFloat finalX = midPoint.x - pictWidth/2.0f;
        self.videoFrame = CGRectMake(xDirection*(self.parentView.bounds.size.width + pictWidth), verticalOffset, pictWidth, pictHeight);
        //NSLog(@"The  pictWidth is %u and height %u", pictWidth, pictHeight);

        // Put the video on the screen.
        NSURL *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:videoName withExtension:@"m4v"];
        self.videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: videoURL];
        self.videoFrame = CGRectMake(finalX, verticalOffset, pictWidth, pictHeight);

        [self.videoPlayer.view setFrame:self.videoFrame];
        self.videoPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
        self.videoPlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
        [self.parentView addSubview:self.videoPlayer.view];
        [self.videoPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [self.videoPlayer play];

        // Add a button for replay and the frame
        self.pictButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        self.pictButton.opaque = NO;
        self.pictButton.contentEdgeInsets = insets;
        [self.pictButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:backGroundFrameName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.pictButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = NO; //Don't want the glow effect on text

        [self.pictButton setFrame:self.videoFrame];
        [self.pictButton addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(videoTapped:)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        [self.parentView addSubview:self.pictButton];

        // The text is placed below the pict so needs to be put on the screen after the pict
        if ( [swipeDirection isEqualToString:@"rotated"] ) {
            [self.textView removeFromSuperview];
            self.textView = nil;
        }
        if (!self.textView) {
            [self createTextFrame];
            [self showTextWithText:videoText];
        } else {
            [self.textView loadHTMLString:@" " baseURL:nil];
        }
    }

    - (void)videoTapped:(UIButton *)buttonPressed {

        id <ShowVideoDelegate> SV_delegate = _delegate;
        [SV_delegate stopSounds];

        [self.videoPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [self.videoPlayer play];
    }

    #pragma mark - Put the text on the screen

    - (void)createTextFrame {

        CGFloat textHeight = 100;
        CGFloat textX = self.parentView.frame.origin.x + self.view.frame.size.width * .05f;
        CGFloat textY = self.videoFrame.origin.y + self.videoFrame.size.height;
        CGFloat textWidth = self.parentView.frame.size.width * .9f;

        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
        if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
            textY = textY + 20;
            if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
                textHeight = textHeight * 1.5f;
                textX = textX + 30;
            } else {
                textHeight = 80; // Full-size text block covers over the scoring
            }
        // Portrait
        } else {
            if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
                textHeight = textHeight * 1.5f;
                textY = textY + 20;
            } else {
                textHeight = textHeight * 1.4f;
                textWidth = self.parentView.frame.size.width;
                textX = 0;
            }
        }
        textWidth = ceilf(textWidth); // Need an integer or else there is a | at the end of the textView
        CGRect textFrame = CGRectMake(textX, textY, textWidth, textHeight);
        self.textView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:textFrame];
        self.textView.opaque = YES;
        self.textView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        [self.parentView insertSubview:self.textView atIndex:0];
    }

    - (void)showTextWithText:(NSString *)textToDisplay {

        NSInteger textFontSize = 14;
        NSString *textFontStyle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"normal"];

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            textFontStyle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bold"];
            textFontSize = 30;
        }
        NSString *formattedText = nil;
        if ( [Globals sharedInstance].showText ) {
            formattedText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<body><style type='text/css'>span.s1 {color:#808080}span.s2 {color: #880000}span.s3 {color: #005500}</style><p style='font-family:sans-serif;text-align:center;font-size:%u;font-weight:%@;'>%@</p></body>", textFontSize, textFontStyle, textToDisplay];
        }
        [self.textView loadHTMLString:formattedText baseURL:nil];
    }

    - (void)removeAllObjectsFromParentView {
        [self.textView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.pictButton removeFromSuperview];

        self.videoPlayer = nil;
        self.textView = nil;
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        self.videoPlayer = nil;
        self.textView = nil;

        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    }

    @end
```

This is the .h file.

```
    //
//  ShowVideo.h
//  Words for SLPs
//
//  Created by John Scarry on 7/26/2013.
//  Copyright 2013 Learning Fundamentals, Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Word.h"

@protocol ShowVideoDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)stopSounds;
@end

@interface ShowVideo : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) Word *word;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *parentView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *videoToDisplay;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *videoPlayer;
@property (nonatomic) CGRect videoFrame;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *pictButton;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *textView;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ShowVideoDelegate> delegate;

- (id)initWithParentView:(UIView *)parentview;

- (void)displaywithVideo:(NSString *)videoName
                withText:(NSString *)videoText
      withSwipeDirection:(NSString *)swipeDirection;

- (void)videoTapped:(UIButton *)buttonPressed;

- (void)createTextFrame;

- (void)showTextWithText:(NSString *)textToDisplay;

- (void)removeAllObjectsFromParentView;
@end
```